# _POST_FBA_INBOUND_CARTON_CONTENTS_ Error

Tags: amazon-mws, amazon-fba

The XML below for FBA carton information is set when we create a shipment.

```xml
 <MessageType>CartonContentsRequest</MessageType>
    <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <CartonContentsRequest>
    <ShipmentId>XXXXKQN8</ShipmentId>
    <NumCartons>3</NumCartons>
    <Carton>
        <CartonId>1</CartonId>
        <Item><SKU>FBA-XXX80</SKU>
        <QuantityShipped>2</QuantityShipped>
        <QuantityInCase>2</QuantityInCase>
        </Item>
    </Carton>    
    <Carton><CartonId>2</CartonId>
    <Item><SKU>FBA-DDESXX11</SKU><QuantityShipped>5</QuantityShipped><QuantityInCase>5</QuantityInCase></Item>
    </Carton>    
    <Carton><CartonId>3</CartonId><Item><SKU>FBA-XXX</SKU><QuantityShipped>5</QuantityShipped><QuantityInCase>5</QuantityInCase></Item></Carton></CartonContentsRequest></Message></AmazonEnvelope>
```

We passed the XML for carton information, but we're getting an error.

Comment: I love secret errors!

Comment: Have you seen this XSD file? https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_4_1/CartonContentsRequest.xsd

Answer (score 3):

whats your error?
i'm uploading this feed Daily i can probably help you
this should work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">  
<Header> <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion> 
<MerchantIdentifier>[SellerID]</MerchantIdentifier> 
</Header> 
<MessageType>CartonContentsRequest</MessageType>
<Message>   
<MessageID>1</MessageID>  
<CartonContentsRequest>
<ShipmentId>[ShipmentID]</ShipmentId>
<NumCartons>2</NumCartons> 
<Carton>
<CartonId>FBA001</CartonId>
<Item><SKU>sellerSKU1</SKU><QuantityShipped>55</QuantityShipped><QuantityInCase>1</QuantityInCase></Item> 
</Carton>  
<Carton>
<CartonId>FBA002</CartonId>
<Item><SKU>sellerSKU2</SKU><QuantityShipped>55</QuantityShipped><QuantityInCase>1</QuantityInCase></Item>
</Carton>  
</CartonContentsRequest> 
</Message> 
</AmazonEnvelope>
```